# Java - Array creation and memory usage

Tags: java, arrays

Pretty elementary question, but here goes: Is there any real kind of difference when creating an array using these two techniques (other than the fact that one takes more time to write)?

```
Double[] array = new Double[3];
array[0] = new Double(1.0);
array[1] = new Double(2.0);
array[2] = new Double(3.0);
```

or

```
Double[] array = new Double[]{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
```

Furthermore, in terms of memory usage, in my first example, does the array declaration already allocate space for the three doubles (in which case, the 3 subsequent lines don't actually increase memory usage)?

Comment: It is the same. Same memory usage.

Comment: No, it hasn't. Only later (the 3 subsequent lines) which will increase the memory usage. however both way will have the same memory usage.

Comment: See the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411815/initializing-static-variables-in-java/25411913#25411913)

Answer (score 0):

No difference, memory usage will be exact same.

Answer (score 0):

The way it reads the second method is almost exactly the same as the way it reads the first. The objects it creates are also exactly the same so neither execution time or memory usage will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Memory usage will be the same as autoboxing will create `Double`s just like you did.

The direct initialization will be faster though becase the array will be filled right away, while in the first case an array with `null` values will be created first, then will it be filled one-by-one each requiring index range check too, and also index value processing too (0, 1, 2 - while in the direct initializaiton you use no index values at all, they are implicit).

Comment: When the array is full of null values in my first example, is it still actually using 3 double's worth of memory? Or does that not occur until I actually create 3 new doubles in the subsequent lines?

Comment: Yes, it does. When you have the reference to the `Double` array, it already is capable of storing references to `Double`s therefore it already occupies the required memory.